# Any testing tool available to test migrated data between different repo?

Tags: svn, migration, aem, data-migration

Am looking for a testing tool or any scripts/code available to test the migrated data from SVN to other repo(not GIT).Please suggest the approach.

Comment: By migrated data do you mean AEM content versioned in SVN?

Comment: Yes.Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, in this case, install two AEM instances with the content to be compared, and use something like this: https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/jcr-compare/index.html

By the way, it is unusual to version AEM content.